# load images efficiently in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I wanna load a large byte[] of colors. In opengl, i want to draw it like a video (for splashscreen).
For now, I'm load each pixmap like GIF, but it takes too much memory (RAM). (I did it on the Android platform with libgdx).

```
public ImageSequences(int width, int height, byte[][] pixmaps) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.frameCount = pixmaps.length;
    this.data = new Pixmap[frameCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
        this.data[i] = new Pixmap(width, height, mainFormat);
        Pixmap p = new Pixmap(pixmaps[i], 0, pixmaps[i].length);
        this.data[i].drawPixmap(p, 0, 0, p.getWidth(), p.getHeight(), 0, 0, width, height);
        p.dispose();
    }
    this.base = new Texture(width, height, mainFormat);
}

int lastIndx = -1;
public Texture getKey(float timeState) {
    int i = Math.round(timeState * 60) % frameCount;
    if (lastIndx == i)
        return base;
    lastIndx = i;
    base.draw(data[i], 0, 0);
    return base;
}
```

And

```
        int I = 574 + 1;// 574
        byte[][] dats = new byte[I][];
        int width = 1400;
        int height = 720;
        for (int i = 0; i < I; i++) {
            dats[i] = Gdx.files.internal(String.format("seq/anim_%05d.jpg", i)).readBytes();
        }
        anim = new ImageSequences(width, height, dats);
```

Using the video player method looks more efficient. Any solution?

I hope, it can be done on multiplatform and without additional libraries.

Edit: with 500+ images and 1280x720 pixels or more high.

Sorry for bad english and Thanks.

Comment: It is not viable to play an animation of that size using a series of textures. It would take up 1.5 GB of memory! You need to use a video to take advantage of video compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use an AssetManager.
AssetManager will handle the asset for you (Multiple use by example).

You have to load your Asset before using it.

```java
this.assetManager.load("Your internal Path", Texture.class);

assetManager.finishLoading();//optional but he just wait the end of assetLoading
```

And after that you can get your Asset.

The load of the asset can be done before in advance asynchronously in the startup of the application or the screen.

You can see more information about it in [libGdx gitHub wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets)

Also I think you should use a Texture instead of PixMap

and

change ImageSequence constructor

```java
public ImageSequences(int width, int height, List<Texture> textures) {
 ....
}
```

After that imageSequence will just have to change the current texture for making the animation.

Texture class will directly handle the bit for you. And the Texture Object can directly be created by the assetManager

```java
Teture texture = assetManager.get("Your internal Path", Texture.class);
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention the number of images that reach up to 500+, 1280x720 pixels. i will change the resource from image to video, but i don't know how to code in opengl/libgdx yet.

Comment: It's a lot no wonder you have RAM size issue. 
You can try https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video 
Who is libgdx sublibrary ()

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to create a custom file that only contains the width, height,frame and colors data. Then read it into animation. Maybe, video is better for the high quality.

Comment: See TextureRegion who can make a selection into a texture